# Is there a way to turn off that anoying drum beat and welcome noise for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I know that windows made the welcome noise for turning on your computer iconic, but it's annoying in the middle of a group.  I can't seem to turn off my sound before Ubuntu boots up, and I'm guessing that It will be easier to turn off all the boot up noises rather than fixing that.

Also if it matters running Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala

Comment: Just replace the ogg file https://opensourceinside.blogspot.in/2017/02/disablingchanging-drum-beat-sound-on.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to test this out beforehand, but

`sudo rm /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/libcanberra-ready-sound.desktop /usr/share/gnome/autostart/libcanberra-login-sound.desktop /usr/share/gnome/shutdown/libcanberra-logout-sound.sh`

should disable all startup-, shutdown-, login-, and logout-sounds systemwide.

A less invasive approach would be to edit the aforementioned files and but a `#` before the lines that contain `canberra-gtk-play`. This would mark them as comments, therefore making the system disregard them. This also "protects" you against the system replacing the missing files during an update or similar.

Comment: This is the only one of the solutions that seemed to actually get rid of the drum-beat login-ready sound.  Thanks

Comment: I still get a single "beat"/"alert" sound in gdm when I do this, but the drums are gone...

Answer (score 3):

I haven't switched to Karmic yet so couldn't test it, but I think this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1313349 should be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn this off in System > Preferences > Sound. Just select "no sounds" for the theme.

It used to be customizable in 9.04.

You can do something more destructive if you want only that sound removed, but this shuts the computer up entirely (something that's nice for laptops).

Answer (score 1):

This had it for the drum beat sound.  Found at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1300051

> alt+F2 gconf-editor
>
> untick the active key in order to
>   disable the login ready drums sound in
>   /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/settings-manager-plugins/sound/

That's only half of it.  I lost the link to where i found the other half but it looks like turning off all sounds in System > Preferences > Sound will do it.  Or more specifically removing the GNOME login sound from the Startup applications in System > Preferences > Startup Applications