# Disable Boot Up and Login Sound in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

In Ubuntu 10.04, how do you disable the sounds that are played when the graphical login screen is shown, and after you login? There used to be a friendly System->Administration dialog to disable these, but every version seems to move everything around or simply drop useful features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly this link may help:

http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-turn-offdownup-login-sound-when-ubuntu-gnome-startup

Comment: Point 1"b" is all that's necessary: System->Administration->Login Screen->uncheck "Play login sound".

Comment: The login sound is one problem. However, there's also the drum-beat sound that's played when the login prompt is displayed.

Comment: you could possible have a look at the solution provided here: http://superuser.com/questions/77667/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-that-anoying-drum-beat-and-welcome-noise-for-ubuntu